# Link to (shortcut) is broken after reboot

Tags: shortcuts

[image]I am running latest version of Ubuntu (16.04) on my machine. Everything is working quite well except that my shortcuts or links are broken to a particular (second internal physical drive) in my machine.

I have read several questions here that generally all have the same answer, IE the drive is not mounted. I don't think this is a mounting issue though. If I go to the exact same folder and create a new (identical link) and place it on my desktop, it works, but if I click on the original old link, it still says it's broken. When I look at the properties for the two links, they are identical (in terms of file path)

The only difference I can see is where it says Type: Link(broken)(inode/symlink)
whereas the working link says Type: Link to Folder (inode/directory)

The working link also has Basic/Permissions and Local Network Share tabs, whereas the broken link now only shows Basic/Permissions and Open Wit

[image: Screenshots of working and broken links]

[image]

this is what I get after a (working) new link or shortcut is put on the desktop, but note, the old one still does not work. Sorry, I don't know how to run this confusing editor, so the broken link is the picture at the top, the working link is the picture at the bottom. If I reboot the machine then the new one will cease to function as well. This is not a mounting issue in my limited opinion, else how can one link work, when the other does not, yet they point to exactly the same location!

This is what the properties look like for a working link:
[image]

Note the tabs are different to the broken link, yet they are created in exactly the same fashion, but change after reboot.

Comment: Run `ls -l <shortcut>` twice; once when the shortcut is working, and once when it isn't. Then [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/811664/edit) the output into your question.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance here, but where, how am I supposed to run that? If I open a terminal window and run it, unsurprisingly it tells me bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

The shortcut is on my Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Replace the part in angle brackets with the file location. In this case, it looks like it's `ls -l /home/graham/Desktop/Music`.

Comment: I have added the info (albeit confusing) to my original question above. Obviously I have still not resolved this. Frustrating, as Windows has no issues making shortcuts that you can drag and drop at will.

Comment: Note I have been unsuccessful making the original link work again. Once broken, it stays broken. Any new links work as expected, but post reboot, are permanently broken too. In order to get the screenshot at the bottom, I made a new link on the desktop with exactly the same path, but different name (can't have two links with the same name on the desktop, this is expected)

Comment: Furthermore, and this may be nothing, but the link "types" seem to change too. A working link looks different on reboot (at which point it no longer works). By looks different, I don't mean the icon, I mean the properties layout or physical properties are different.

Comment: To clarify, the two top pictures are for broken links, the two bottom pictures are for working links. Or at least I think the 3rd picture is for the working link, only because it changed colour when I added a working link to the desktop.

Comment: OK, next thing to do is have one working link and one not-working link at the same time, and run `ls -l` on them.

Comment: @witenitenz did you ever get this fixed? I've come accross the exact same problem and I dont get it.  Both the links (old and newly created) point to the same path.  yet one doesnt work.

Comment: @witenitenz https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: @Chud37 I didn't fix it as such, instead the problem seemed to "resolve" itself. I keep my updates on, and as such am always up to date (16.04 Desktop). I gave up on the icons/shortcuts for a long time, and then returned to them many months later, and found that they were working. Wish I could tell you more, but for now the solution (for me) was update your Linux version.

Comment: I have the same problem, it's frustrating. Coming from Windows I find Ubuntu full of bugs like this, tiny things here and there, that I use to take for granted in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is occured because the link which you have created is on the drive which do not mount automatically on startup so first you need to change the mount options for that particular drive which you simply can do by just simply searching the 'Disk' and change the mount options turn off the User Session Default option.